# How to use Mersenne Twister random number generation library in C?

Tags: c, random, mersenne-twister

I want to use one of the Mersenne Twister C libraries (e.g. [tinymt](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/TINYMT/index.html), [mtwist](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~geoff/mtwist.html), or libbrahe) <strike>so I can use it as a seed for `rand()`</strike> in a C program. I wasn't able to find a simple minimalistic example on how to do this.

I got this far with the mtwist package, but through pjs's comments I've realized that this is the wrong way to do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mtwist.h"

int main() {
    uint32_t random_value;

    random_value = mt_lrand();
    srand(random_value);
    printf("mtwist random: %d; rand: %d\n", random_value, rand());

    return 0;
}
```

(Originally I wrote that this code wouldn't compile, but thanks to Carl Norum's answer I was able to compile it afterall.)

Could anyone give me a simple example on how to properly generate random numbers with any Mersenne Twister C library?

Comment: Mersenne Twister is a much better PRNG than `rand()`, why on earth would you use it just to seed rather than as a replacement for `rand()`?  Your question hints at a serious underlying conceptual flaw.

Comment: @pjs: Hmm, you're right. I'm not thinking straight. Forget about `rand()` then. I'd still appreciate a simple example.

Comment: If you've downloaded `mtwist`, the source comes with an example of how to use: `run-mtwist.c`.  The key thing with pseudo-random number generators is to seed it ONCE AND ONLY ONCE, then let it do its thing.  Neophytes tend to think that by constantly re-seeding they are somehow improving the randomness, when in reality this messes it up.

Comment: @pjs: Actually, Mersenne Twister is fairly over-rated. I'd give it a 50% chance of being better than the system's `rand()` since glibc's `rand()` is actually BSD `random()`, a much better PRNG than Mersenne Twister or the typical LCG PRNGs used for `rand()`. Anyway, a 64-bit LCG with Mersenne Twister's tempering function tacked onto it is probably just as good as, and a lot lighter and faster than, Mersenne Twister, for the vast majority of purposes.

Comment: @R.. The question referred to using `rand()` in C, I haven't seen anything to indicate that the original poster was using glibc.  I stand by my statement that MT is way better than the typical LCG implementation of `rand()`.

Comment: @pjs: I was just mentioning that one of the most common standard library implementations has a `rand()` implementation that's superior to Mersenne Twister, meaning that the question of whether it's an improvement or not is highly system-specific and, without knowing which system OP is using, a toss-up.

Comment: @pjs: Curious. I have downloaded the source archive, but it does not come with `run-mtwist.c`. I've looked at the other .c files, but they are all too complicated for me.

Comment: @R..: I'm running Linux so I'm guessing I'm using glibc's `rand()`. If what you are saying is true, than I'd rather use `rand()`. But I have yet to find a good seed for it. I guess I should make that into a separate question.

Comment: I know this point has already been made, but Mersenne Twister has to be seeded anyway. (And I understand that if you give MT a seed with a lot of zeros, it can take a long time for it to recover and start giving decent pseudo-random numbers.)

Comment: You say that using `srand(time(NULL))` and `rand()` "gives results that aren't random enough". What *exactly* do you mean by that? Are you concerned about predictability, distribution, or something else? What are your requirements?

Comment: @KeithThompson: If you generate multiple random numbers within a second time, the numbers will be the same (probably because `time(NULL)` is only precise to the second). By the way, I've removed that statement from the questions, as it is unrelated to the main question.

Comment: @SerranoPereira: Use the `tv_nsec` field from `clock_gettime` as a seed, or read `sizeof(int)` bytes from `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: @SerranoPereira Apologies, `run-mtwist.c` wasn't part of the distribution.  I've provided source below as an answer.

Comment: @R..: Thanks for the `time(NULL)` alternatives!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a demo of how to use the `mtwist` implementation of Mersenne Twister:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mtwist.h"

int main(void) {
   int i;
   mt_seed();
   for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      printf("%f\n", mt_ldrand());
   }
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compiled and run as follows:

```
[pjs@amber:mtwist-1.4]$ gcc run-mtwist.c mtwist.c
[pjs@amber:mtwist-1.4]$ ./a.out
0.817330
0.510354
0.035416
0.625709
0.410711
0.980872
0.965528
0.444438
0.705342
0.368748
[pjs@amber:mtwist-1.4]$
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not a compiler error, it's a linker error.  You're missing the appropriate `-l` flag to link the library you're using.  Your compiler invocation should look something like:

```
cc -o example example.c -lmtwist
```

I just took a quick look at the mtwist page you linked to, and it appears to be distributed just as source, not as a library.  In that case, adding the appropriate implementation file to your command line should work:

```
cc -o example example.c mtwist.c
```

But you probably should look into a `make`-based solution that builds a real library out of the mtwist code.

Comment: But I don't have a library installed for that package. I just have the header file. I'm I supposed to create a library from the header file or something?

Comment: No - if you have only the header file you're out of luck.  You need to find the implementation and link it in.  Editing answer...

Comment: Thanks Carl! That solved the linker error. However, `mt_lrand()` keeps generating the same number, but I'd expect a different number each time I execute the program.

Comment: @Serrano Pereira: All pseudo-random number generators always generate exactly the same sequence of pseudo-random numbers starting from the given seed value. That is exactly what MT will do as well, until you provide it with varying seed value at startup.

Comment: @AndreyT: I suppose that depends on what you mean by "pseudo-random number generators". `/dev/urandom` and `/dev/random` give you pseudo-random numbers, but they're not repeatable. But yes, MT gives repeatable results for a given seed (and MT's seed is not a single number).

Comment: @KeithThompson I thought that /dev/random gives you actual random numbers. Still deterministic on the majority of machines (lack of non-deterministic hardware RNGs,) since it uses environment noise from sources like the network or interrupts, but still random. Only /dev/urandom will switch to pseudo-random numbers when the entropy pool is depleted.

Comment: @NikosC.: Depends on what you mean by "actual random numbers". *Truly* random numbers, as I understand the term, cannot be deterministic. (You could probably configure a system to use a [hardware RNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator) as input to `/dev/random`. And my understanding is that `/dev/urandom` is as good as `/dev/random` for all, or almost all, purposes. Note that you can have completely predictable pseudo-random numbers that meet all mathematical tests for randomness; sometimes that's exactly what you want.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yeah, there's some disagreement on what is random. As I perceive it, something like the roll of a dice (which is what /dev/random is) is random but deterministic. Observing a quantum event (like whether a photon passes through a mirror or not) is non-deterministic. But in my view, both qualify as "random" with non-deterministic randomness getting the "truly" prefix :-)

Comment: @NikosC.: The roll a die (singular "die", plural "dice") could be non-deterministic. If you could analyze all the interactions of a rolling die with its surroundings, as well as the mental processes of the person rolling it, it could well depend on quantum-mechanical processes. (Ultimately everything does.)

Comment: @NikosC.: I like to go with the classics.  Random == "Not predictable with certainty".  The degree of uncertainty can be quantified with measures such as entropy.

Comment: @KeithThompson If the roll of a die (thanks, I feel like Larry Laffer now ;-) can be considered non-deterministic, than /dev/random must be too though; the movement of a user's mouse or the amount of time between keyboard presses feels very similar to rolling dice.

Comment: @NikosC.: I'll just flip a coin to decide whether it's truly random or not.