# Mersenne Twister (mt19937ar.c) not returning random number

Tags: c, random, random-seed, mersenne-twister

I tried searching for examples on how to use the [mt19937ar.c](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/MT2002/CODES/mt19937ar.c) variant of **Mersenne Twister** but most come up in **C++** and [others seem to use `mtwist.h`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550656/how-to-implement-mersenne-twister-random-number-generation-in-c).

My code below:

```
int getRandomNum(void)
{
    int i;
    i = (int) genrand_int32();
    return i;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ...
    int m = getRandomNum();
    printf("m = %d", m);
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

simply spits out the same integer over and over again. Seems like a seeding issue, but every implementation that I've found of getting a random number with `mt19937` simply just invokes `genrand_int32()`. Am I doing this incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mersenne Twister is not magical; it has no way of producing random results from predictable input. If you want a random sequence, you have to seed the generator by calling `init_genrand()` with some sort of unique value. Otherwise it'll use a fixed default seed (specifically: 5489).

An easy value to use is the current time:

```
init_genrand(time(NULL));
```

Don't call this more than once during your program, though -- otherwise, you'll restart the sequence!

Comment: Thanks! This helped.

Comment: Your first sentence is not really valid, it could seed the rng if not given a seed explicitly.  No magic is required...

Comment: @Apollys As explained in my answer, the implementation used by the OP defaults to a seed of 5489. It's a very old portable implementation, so it can't use functions like `time()`. (They don't exist on all platforms!)